# Django - How to store emojis in postgres DB properly?

Tags: django, postgresql, react-native

I'm running the latest version of Django on postgres. I'm trying to store emojis in my postgres DB in a way that a React Native app can properly render it. Below I have the initial emojis variables setup that'll go into the table. I've copy and pasted the emojis from [here](https://emojipedia.org/). How do I store emojis in my postgres DB so that a React Native app can render it properly?

[image]

I tried following this [blog](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/03/31/using-emojis-in-django-model-fields), which suggests adding ’OPTIONS’: {’charset’: ’utf8mb4’} to `DATABASES` under `settings.py`, but I get this error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "charset"`. Seems like this only works for MySQL DBs. **How can I store emojis in a Django postgres DB?**

Comment: Don't you need to put emojis inside quotes in Python? Otherwise Python won't know it's a string.

Comment: @NickODell sorry yes I did that post taking this screenshot

Comment: You know, if you copy-paste the code into the question, it will be easier to update than a screenshot when the code changes because you fixed an issue.

Comment: @NickODell fair point, but it isn't the main issue at hand it's more storing these strings in the postgres DB. But yes you do make a good point.

Comment: Now that you've fixed the quotes, try removing that `charset` option. It's entirely possible it'll just work. If not, include the resulting error message.

Comment: @AdamKG make that an answer and about how postgresql already supports unicode and I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Like in the comments suggested, you need to put quotes around the emojis since they're just chars. Though, something like flags is actually two chars. So that's something to be careful about. All your computer is doing is converting unicode to a rendered emoji that's platform dependent.

The emojis that you're using should be unicode supported. On your computer, they're definitely supported. For the most part, additional unicode support for new emojis is very quickly implemented once published on client machines. There should be no problem with emojis in strings. This is a nice video kinda explaining emojis by Tom Scott who keeps getting interviews about emojis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTzp76JXsoY

I'm not an expert so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your models you need to use a `CharField` or a `TextField` to store emojis, that need to be passed as characters (for example `""` and not directly ). Your database must use utf8 to support emojis, connect to your database with a SQL shell, to check the current encoding run:

```sql
SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;
```

If the output is not `UTF8` run:

```sql
SET CLIENT_ENCODING='UTF8';
```

Now remove `’OPTIONS’: {’charset’: ’utf8mb4’}` from your Django settings.